# google site rank from search word

Tags: api, ranking

is it possible (a Google API or something) to get the ranking of a website given a search word?  It's the code equivalent of doing a Google search for a word, then browsing through the results until you find the website you look for.

By ranking I mean the position in the pages found, e.g. the site is number 4000 when searching for some word.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such API. One reason for that is that with the growing personalization, it's unlikely that there is going to be a single answer at any given time, even for users in the same location.

Also, since automated queries against the search results are against Google's TOS, you would probably be better off just searching manually for your pages.

Comment: So how do you think www.googlerankings.com gets their results?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Google API key, you can use this website, though it will also do other search engines.

[www.googlerankings.com](http://www.googlerankings.com/)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks.  It's a start, but I'm more interested in what they are doing to get the results.

Answer (score 0):

Via Google AJAX Search API you can search and receive results as JSON/XML, just search for your keywords and check the results for your landing page.

There is a PHP Class for it: 
http://bohuco.net/blog/2010/07/google-ranking-checker-class-in-php/